# how to use last inserted record id to multiple tables

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have 3 table, Merchant_Master, Merchant_PaymentDetail, and Merchant_refference
Master table looks like this and Id is the Autoincrement

```
  +----+------+------------+----------------+
  | id | mid  | acquirerID |   merchantName |
  +----+------+------------+----------------+
  |  1 | 2345 |          3 |  store 1       |
  +----+------+------------+----------------+
```

Merchant_PaymentDetail looks like this, the first Column is AutoIncrement

```
   +----+-----+--------+-------------+
   | id | mid | BankID |   AccountNo |
   +----+-----+--------+-------------+
   |    |     |        |             |
   +----+-----+--------+-------------+
```

and Merchant_Refference table looks like this, the first Column is AutoIncrement

```
  +----+-----+--------+---------------------+
  | id | mid | Reference 1  |   Reference 2 |
  +----+-----+--------------+---------------+
  |    |     |              |               |
  +----+-----+--------------+---------------+
```

now I want to insert the records to all three tables using insert statement but how do I get the same mid from the merchant master table to the other two tables 
(mid is not AutoIncremented), do I have to use @@IDENTITY to achieve this or is there any other way.

Comment: You use terms like "AutoIncrement" and "last insert id".  These are usually associated with MySQL.  Are you sure you are using SQL Server?  If so, only one version is appropriate.

Comment: yes I am using SQL server

Comment: Can you clear it up a bit for us... so you want to insert into all three tables the same `mid` which **is not an IDENTITY column** (not autoincremented) in any of them? Why not just insert the same value into all three, what's stopping you?

Comment: I have one form where I have  to take input from the user  and insert the records into three tables, I am using  stored procedure to insert the records

Comment: Since you're using form for user input, and store procedure to do the rest. Then use variables, which will hold the user input data and you can use them in insert statements.

Comment: This sample is not clear could you explain more

Answer (score 1):

With the additional information you posted in the comments, your stored procedure should look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcName
  @mid int,
  @acquirerID int,
  ...
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SET XACT_ABORT ON;

  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  INSERT INTO Merchant_Master (mid, acquirerID, merchantName)
    VALUES (@mid, @acquirerID, '...');

  INSERT INTO Merchant_PaymentDetail (mid, BankID, AccountNo)
    VALUES (@mid, ..., ...);

  INSERT INTO Merchant_Refference (mid, [Reference 1], [Reference 2])
    VALUES (@mid, ..., ...);

  COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END;
```

That way, you insert the same `mid` into all three tables within a transaction and all of your `IDENTITY` (first) columns will get their autoincremented value.

Comment: Then what is the problem? What error do you get or what do you want for it to do that it does not at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Merchant_Master (mid, acquirerID, merchantName)
VALUES...

DECLARE @mid INT = (SELECT mid FROM Merchant_Master WHERE id = SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

...then use the `@mid` variable in your `INSERT` statements to the other tables